# Screenshot of a screen changing dynamically

Tags: android

How to take screenshot of a activity screen programmatically where a part of the screen is getting refreshed dynamically.I am getting the previous image each time because of caching.

Comment: how do i refesh it?i want to take screenshot of a few charts.but i am getting only first one and after that it is caching

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take a screenshot of part of your application you can use method [View.getDrawingCache().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29)

Comment: i am getting the screenshot using View.getDrawingCache() but problem is cahcing means whatever screen i selected first only that one i'm getting repeatedly.

Comment: i am not getting what exactly you want plz explain more

Comment: I am using an activity which has one linear layout and another frame layout.There is a spinner in linear layout,where if i select different values it'll load different types of chart in the frame layout.But i'm only getting images of whatever i selected first when i try to print all images.